# Not getting required characteristics in BLE

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am complete newbie in `BLE` and here is my understanding.

1) There are services.

2) For each service there are characteristics.

3) Using those characteristics we must set value like `00x10`.

I am facing many issues with device.
I am trying to scan my `BLE` device. I am doing the same with `ARF` app.The `arf` app detects services name synonymous to the one provided for my `BLE` device sheet like "`3fc2d576-0249-11e7-93ae-9236-----`"

My code is

```
List<BluetoothGattService> services;
            services = gatt.getServices();
           Log.d("++++size++++",""+services.size());
            for(int i=0;i<services.size();i++) {
                Log.d("++++++",services.get(i).getUuid().toString());
                for(int j=0;j<services.get(i).getCharacteristics().size();j++){
                    Log.d("characteristcs",""+services.get(i).getUuid());
                }
            }
```

My understanding is there are services and then for each service there are characteristics.
   So in my code these are the kind of values I am getting

> > D/characteristcs: 675465da-ff3e-c5b7-1266-c58586f77889
> >     12-21 11:49:59.682 16991-17003/com.root.newbleproject D/characteristcs: 675465da-ff3e-c5b7-1266-c58586f77889
> >     12-21 11:49:59.682 16991-17003/com.root.newbleproject D/++++++: 0000180f-0000-1000-8000--------
> >     12-21 11:49:59.682 16991-17003/com.root.newbleproject D/characteristcs: 0000180f-0000-1000-8000------
> >     12-21 11:49:59.682 16991-17003/com.root.newbleproject D/++++++: 00001805-0000-1000-8000-------

The one preceding with ++++++ are characteristics under every service and rest is service. What am I doing wrong ??? Also some one please let me know how do I identify which service should be primary and how to detect the service I need to use in my application ?
  Thanks.

Comment: It seems your log is incomplete? It doesn't contain "++++size++++".

Comment: I have not printed but size is 11,size of service list.

Comment: It is hard to understand your exact question. If you have not made the peripheral, you need to read its documentation to understand which characteristics you should use.

Comment: Hi,Thanks @Emil It was connectivity issue. I have found my primary service "3fc2d576-0249-11e7-93ae-9236------" which is visible in ARF , under this there are characteristics on which I need to work on, I have used getIncludedServices() but it returns zero , can you let me know which method to use to get the values inside this service ? They start with name similar to this service that is 3fc2----- Thanks :)